# Custom Textbox Not Focused When Tab and Shift+Tab is Pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, custom-controls

I have a `CustomTextBox` control It comes with Place HolderText.
The Style of the control is Like this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:WaterMarkTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:WaterMarkTextBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="PART_GridControl"
                      Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                      Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PART_PlaceHolderTextBlock"                                   
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="20,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBox  x:Name="PART_PlaceHolderTextBox"
                              Background="Transparent"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                              FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                              FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                              Padding="20,0,150,0" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But When I press the tab its not get Focused. Please help me to sort out of this problem. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `Focusable="True"` for text box ?

Comment: @AbinMathew I tried that, in that control Focused Event If I set textbox.Focus(true) then tab control working fine but shift+tab Not working.

Comment: You may be having more than one control which does not have `Focusable"` set to `true`. make sure all your controls have the property set to `true`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588688(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AbinMathew I tried that but its not working. and I tried TabIndex also thats also not working